# Octave: Can't interact with a window while a script is pausing

Tags: matlab, octave

I am working on an octave script that displays many plots and I would like to pause my script for a while (for example with pause) at some point and interact with some plots but it seems they are "locked" during pauses. I have to continue the script and wait the end of it to interact with those plots.

Comment: the `keyboard()` function could be used instead of `pause` it will return control to you and then the script can be continued by running `return` or `dbcont` in hte prompt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `pause` is to pause the execution, and is not meant to give you back control of the Octave prompt.

What you are looking for is the command `keyboard`. This will you drop you in debug mode so you can whatever you want, change plots, variables, etc. When you are finished, you can continue execution of the script with `dbcont` (debug -- continue).